# Restrict django form ForeignKey dropdown by user

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models, Group, and List Item.  List Items belong inside Groups:

```
class List_Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("List Item Name", max_length=200, unique = True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, verbose_name="Group")

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField("Creation Date", default=datetime.now)
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Group Name", max_length=200, unique = True)
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my forms for List Items, a ModelForm has a dropdown for Groups.  Currently, it lists all Groups, regardless of which user a Group belongs to. But I want to only display Groups that belong to the user logged in.  How might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to override the form field inside the **init** method. You could pass the logged in user to the form from the view and filter based on it

```
#form
class ListItemform(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, ** kwargs):
            self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
            super(ListItemform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['group'].queryset = Group.objects.filter(user = self.user)
#view
def displayform(request):
    user = request.user
    form = ListItemForm(user = user)
    return ...
```